# IEnumerable Any() with a simple int[]

Tags: c#, arrays, ienumerable, any, entitycollection

Quick question:  I'm comparing the IDs of entities in an EF4 EntityCollection against a simple int[] in a loop.  I'd like to do something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Collection.Count; ++i)
{
    Array.Any(a => a.value == Collection[i].ID) ? /* display yes */ : /* display no */;
}
```

I'm just not sure how to compare the value within the array with the value from the EntityCollection, or, in other words, what to use for real instead of the value property I made up above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code should be modified to read:

```
int[] arr = //this is the integer array
IEnumerable Collection = //This is your EF4 collection
for (int i = 0; i < Collection.Count; ++i)
{
    arr.Any(a => a == Collection[i].ID) ? /* display yes */ : /* display no */;
}
```

I called out a few variables at the top just so we're clear as to what is what.  The major part that changed was that instead of invoking `Array.Any` we're invoking `arr.Any`.  `Any` is an Extension method for `int[]` and thus you invoke it on the array itself, not on the class `Array`.

Does this solve the problem?

Comment: This may result in all rows being fetched from the database! This may be a performance hit.

Comment: In my case, I want to take all rows from the db.  It's intentional behavior, with only 10 or so rows retrieved.  That particular db table will never grow, so it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

skip the loop and you can do something like this

```
array.Any(a => collection.Any(c => c.ID == a)) ? /* display yes */ : /* display no */;
```

if you need the loop then you can skip the second `Any()` from above and do

```
array.Any(a => collection.ElementAt(i).ID == a) ? /* display yes */ : /* display no */;
```

Comment: Can't skip the loop, as I'm doing something else with the Entities in the loop.

Comment: @kevinmajor1 ah I see. I have added another snipped that will work with the loop.